# Equivalent of html() method or innerHTML attribute for XMl document

Tags: jquery, xml, innerhtml, dom-traversal

When display a DOM tree I usually use jQuery method html() or DOM attribute innerHTML. However, they both don't work with XML tree.

I wonder if there is anything equivalent to these 2 methods for XML tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the node content by

```
$(this).find('somenode').text();
```

And other properties:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var title = $(this).find('title').text();
// where this is the some node, in $.each for ex.
```

Comment: text() only shows the text content of a node. What I need is the dom tree, atma. Thanks for responding anyway.

Comment: **innerHTML** only works for HTML documents, so you can not use native JS property in XML. Node can contain HTML only in CDATA tag. You can not use XML tree AS DOM node. The only way is to process every known node. Just take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/atma/eTkvv/)

Comment: Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/atma/eTkvv/2/), without console. And check the basic [XML object properties](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_attribute.asp)